# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) using aysnc Task

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to post multiple table rows into the db. The class is "PurchaseOrderDetail" I understand i need to deserialize the JSON but I am not sure how to do that using the async Task IHttpActionResult method. 
Error Message

> {"$id":"1","Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"$id":"2","newPurchaseOrderDetail":["Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'TexasExterior.Models.PurchaseOrderDetail' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1."]}}

ApiController

```
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostNewPurchaseOrderDetail([FromBody]PurchaseOrderDetail newPurchaseOrderDetail)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                context.PurchaseOrderDetails.Add(newPurchaseOrderDetail);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return CreatedAtRoute("PurchaseOrderDetailApi", new { newPurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderDetailId }, newPurchaseOrderDetail);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return this.BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

JSON

```
[
    {
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERPARTNUMBER": "Panels",
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTENOTES": "Notes",
        "QBRFQGROUPCOMBINESIZES": 15,
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEQTY": 150,
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEUOM": "ft",
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEUNITPRICE": 1542,
        "$$hashKey": "object:96"
    },
    {
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERPARTNUMBER": "Carpet",
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTENOTES": "Notes",
        "QBRFQGROUPCOMBINESIZES": 205,
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEQTY": 845,
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEUOM": "meter",
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEUNITPRICE": 745893,
        "$$hashKey": "object:98"
    },
    {
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERPARTNUMBER": "Drywall",
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTENOTES": "Notes",
        "QBRFQGROUPCOMBINESIZES": 19,
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEQTY": 45,
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEUOM": "sheet",
        "QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEUNITPRICE": 8542,
        "$$hashKey": "object:100"
    }
]
```

Angular

```
 //Post Purchase Order Detail
$scope.newPurchaseOrderDetail = {};
$scope.newPurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderId = $scope.newPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderId;
$scope.newPurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderDetailId = $scope.newPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderId;
$scope.addPurchaseOrderDetail = function () {
    var newPurchaseOrderDetail = $scope.newPurchaseOrderDetail;
    var index = 0;
    $scope.purchaseOrderDetailArray.forEach(function (newPurchaseOrderDetail) {
        console.log('purchaseOrderDetailArray #' + (index++) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(newPurchaseOrderDetail));
    });
    var data = JSON.stringify($scope.purchaseOrderDetailArray)
    PurchaseOrderDetailPost.post(data)
        .success(function () {
            toastr.success('Success!');
        }).error(function () {
            toastr.error('Error!');
        })

};
```

Factory

```
app.factory('PurchaseOrderDetailPost', function ($http) {
return {

    post: function (data) {
        return $http.post('/api/apiPurchaseOrderDetail/', data);
    }
   };
 })
```

Update

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostNewPurchaseOrderDetail([FromBody]IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderDetail> newPurchaseOrderDetail)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                context.PurchaseOrderDetails.AddRange(newPurchaseOrderDetail);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return CreatedAtRoute("PurchaseOrderDetailApi", new { newPurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderDetailId }, newPurchaseOrderDetail);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return this.BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Error
I know Im close, i dont know how to insert the PurchaseOrderDetailId

```
return CreatedAtRoute("PurchaseOrderDetailApi", new { newPurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderDetailId }, newPurchaseOrderDetail);
```

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? How do you expect to put an array into that object parameter?

Comment: I don't understand what needs to be changed. I have never posted multiple records at once so I am lost

Comment: Either pass a single object as your request, or change the function to accept an array or collection.

Comment: If your json is a serialised array of `PurchaseOrderDetail` objects then change your parameter to an `IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderDetail>`.

Comment: Can you post the Json you are posting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is usually because you are posting something like

```
[{"foo":"bar"}]
```

when you should be posting simply

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

Or modify your method to accept arrays of your class:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostNewPurchaseOrderDetail(
    [FromBody]IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderDetail> newPurchaseOrderDetails)
{
    // ...
```

Make sure the JSON you are posting is in the format you are expecting with something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

---

Your code suggest that you only want to post a single `PurchaseOrderDetails`, but the JSON you have provided implies that you are trying to post many.

You need to choose either to only post one `{...}` or modify your method such that it accepts many `[{...}, {...}]` as I mentioned above.

Comment: Well it depends. How is it being posted?

Comment: So the JSON you posted shows that you're trying to send multiple instances of `PurchaseOrderDetails`. You either need to post only one, or change your class to accept multiple.

Comment: i just updated. correct, I am trying to Post multiple instances. So if I need to modify the JSON it would be in the factory/service?

Comment: Well if you're trying to post multiple, you'll need to change your method to accept multiple. Or only post one at a time!

Comment: should i mark the answer as correct and ask a new question?

Comment: @texas697 Definitely, keeping extending questions isn't the best way to get the answer to your questions - keep them focused and if you have further questions, create a new one and link, saying it follows on from this one. For example, you're now asking about Angular, which I have very limited knowledge on. Asking _that part_ as a new question and tagging as angular will get those experts on your case :)